# Angular Material Installation +

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting the below error when trying install Angular Material.

UPDATE package.json (1403 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'
Require stack:

```
- /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cdk/schematics/utils/build-component.js

- /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cdk/schematics/utils/index.js

- /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cdk/schematics/index.js

- /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/material/schematics/ng-add/setup-project.js


 - /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js


 - /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js


  - /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js


  - /Users/auks/Desktop/blog/material/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js


  - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
```

- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

Angular CLI Version details.

Angular CLI: 10.0.0-rc.5

Comment: Are you sure Angular CLI is correctly installed and available in your project folder?

Comment: Yes.Other than material ,everything is working fine.

Comment: Would it be compatibility issue?

Comment: It was the version compatibility issue